# How to build gstreamer from source code using meson?

Tags: gstreamer, meson-build

OS: Windows 10

Compiler: gcc x86-64 8.1.0

I cloned repo:

```
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer.git
```

Started meson:

```
meson \path\to\directory
```

And next start ninja

```
ninja
```

And I get error:

```
fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
```

I thought that everything what I need is in this repo. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess meson outputs "glib2 not found".
You might need to install glib2.
And make sure glib-2.0.pc exists on "/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig" or $PKG_CONFIG_PATH dir.
meson search pkgconfig dir first for find out package.